# Matlab Current Folder Tab automatically reflect open file

Tags: matlab

I would like the current folder tab to automatically update whenever I open a new .m file in the editor. So the current folder tab will always be open to the folder of the file being displayed in the editor. Is this supported in Matlab? I know Visual Studio has a feature like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB doesn't do that. Perhaps this might be close enough for you though: if you enable the Document Bar in the editor (if it's hidden, go Desktop menu->Document Bar->Bar Position->Select a Position). Now open a file in the editor. If you right-click on its element in the Document Bar, there's an option to change the current folder to the location of the file. So not automatic, but only one click away.